# NGINX try_files in a subfolder else send to php

Tags: nginx

I am trying to figure out how to get nginx to try and find a file in a subfolder, otherwise send it's request to a php file to be handled, for example:

requested file: http://somesite.com/css/style.css
actual file: http://somesite.com/content/css/style.css

```
location /mycms/ {
  try_files /mycms/content/$uri /mycms/content/$uri/ /mycms/index.php?$args;
}
```

But this does not work, any suggestions on how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 3):

you're using `$uri` in a wrong way, try this instead

```
location ~ /mycms/(.*) {
  try_files /mycms/content/$1 /mycms/content/$1/ /mycms/index.php?$query_string;
}
```