# Nginx with CakePHP in subfolder not serving static files (CSS, JS, IMG)

Tags: php, cakephp, nginx

I am trying to setup a Nginx server configuration to serve a CakePHP installation from and to a subfolder.

- URL: `https://sub.domain.com/cakefolder`
- Folder on system: `/var/www/domain/sub/cakefolder`

So i am using a sub folder for both the URL as well as on the system. Now it took me a while to figure the following config out with which requests are properly handled by CakePHP. This means it's correctly bootstraping and handling controllers.

**What doesn't work however, is serving static files from the `webroot` directory (e.g. *.css files) as those are all interpreted as CakePHP controllers leading to a `CssController could not be found.` error.**

My site.conf:

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  listen *:443 ssl;
  server_name sub.domain.com;
  ssl_certificate ./ssl/domain.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key ./ssl/domain.key;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
    rewrite ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
  }

  root /var/www/domain/sub/cakefolder/;
  autoindex off;
  index index.php;

  location /cakefolder {
    root /var/www/domain/sub/cakefolder/app/webroot/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /cakefolder/index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
```

**How do I stop Nginx from routing existing static files through the FastCGI PHP interpreter?**

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/22550332/671047 I already tried replacing my `location /cakefolder { ... }` with

```
 
location ~ /cakefolder/(.*) {
  try_files /cakefolder/$1 /cakefolder/$1/ /cakefolder/index.php?$args;
}
```

but this leads to a redirection loop causing a HTTP 500 error.

**Solution (thanks Pete!):**

I found the following additional directive to be working for this specific setup. This might not be the most elegant solution but who cares, glad it's working for now.

```
location ~* /cakefolder/(.*)\.(css|js|ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$ {
  root /var/www/domain/sub/cakefolder/app/webroot/;
  try_files /$1.$2 =404;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Thorben and pete. The solution that Thorben posted is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could catch it early:

```
            location ~* \.(css|js|ico)$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
            }
```

i have a similar setup and that worked for me when i experienced the same thing (just not cake.) I won't lie, i never understood why the try_files w/redirect always failed on existing static files, where as throwing a try_files like ^above finds the file np. ideas on that? (perhaps today is a source-reading day)

Comment: Thanks mister! With this directive I am getting a 404 which at least means the requests were filtered correctly stopping them from being processed by CakePHP. See my complete solution above.

Comment: if you can post the logged error from your 404, im interested to see what file it attempted